# How to remove the selected data from saved data when we click on button in a selected one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, foreach

In my application I have saved the data when we click on it(we can add the multiple data by entering some data and save the multiple data by clicking the save button).

**.component.html**

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let categoryDetail of selectedCategoryDetails">
      <div class="__header">
        <div>
          <b>{{ categoryDetail.category }}</b>
        </div>
         </div>

      <div
        class="clinical-note__category__details"
        *ngIf="categoryDetail.showDetails">
      
        <ul>
          <li class="habit-list"
            *ngFor="let habits of categoryDetail.habitDetails" >
        
            <div class="target-details">
              <b>{{ clinicalNoteLabels.target }}: </b
              ><span class="habit-list__value">{{ habits.target }}</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="habit-footer">
       <span class="m-l-10"  
          [popoverOnHover]="false"
          type="button"
          [popover]="customHabitPopovers"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i> Delete</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clinical-note__popoverdelete">

        <popover-content #customHabitPopovers [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
          <h5>Do you want to delete this habit?</h5>
          <button
          class="btn-primary clinical-note__save"  (click)="deletedata(habits);customHabitPopovers.hide()">yes </button>
       
        </popover-content></div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

In the above code when we click on delete button it will show some popup having buttons yes(implemented in above code) and now so my requirement is when we clcik on yes button in from the popover it has to delete the particular one.

**.component.ts**

```
 public saveHealthyHabits() {
    let isCategoryExist = false;
    let categoryDetails = {
      category: this.clinicalNoteForm.controls.category.value,
      habitDetails: this.healthyHabits.value,
      showDetails: true,
    };
    if (this.customHabitList.length) {
      categoryDetails.habitDetails = categoryDetails.habitDetails.concat(
        this.customHabitList
      );
      this.customHabitList = [];
    }

    if (this.selectedCategoryDetails) {
      this.selectedCategoryDetails.forEach((selectedCategory) => {
        if (selectedCategory.category === categoryDetails.category) {
          isCategoryExist = true;
          selectedCategory.habitDetails = selectedCategory.habitDetails.concat(
            categoryDetails.habitDetails
          );
        }
      });
    }
    if (!this.selectedCategoryDetails || !isCategoryExist) {
      this.selectedCategoryDetails.push(categoryDetails);
    }

    this.clinicalNoteForm.patchValue({
      category: null,
    });
    this.healthyHabits.clear();
public deletedata(habits){
   if (this.selectedCategoryDetails) {
    this.selectedCategoryDetails.forEach((selectedCategory) => {
  
      if (selectedCategory.category ==categoryDetails.category) {
        isCategoryExist = true;
       
       this.selectedCategoryDetails.splice(habits, 1);
      }
    });
   }
  }
```

The above code I have written  is for saving the data(we can enter multiple data and save multiple )

Like the above I have to delete the particular one when we click on yes button from the popover.

Can anyone help me on the same

Comment: How do you get the selected `categoryDetails` value? Are you iterating over `selectedCategoryDetails` in view to display the individual items?

Comment: yes @Misha Mashina I am iterating the SelectedCategoryDetails in view, and from this iterating SelectedCategoryDetails I have to delete the particular one based on clciking can you please help me on this

Comment: Then you can add index of the current `categoryDetails` to ngFor of `selectedCategoryDetails` and pass the index with `deletedata(index)` and in the method just do `selectedCategoryDetails.splice(index, 1)`.

Comment: thanks@ Misha Mashina, could you please edit the above code with the requirement then it will be more helpful for me

Comment: @Misha Mashina, basically if I use the index is is reoving the first itementered insted of clciked one and also I have edited the code above with some changes could you please look in to that and help me on the same for my requirement then it will be more helpful for me

Comment: Your `deletedata` is out of the scope of ngFor that lists `habits`, so it's not going to work like that. Indeed, if the button stays at that place, you will need to pass it either the `categoryDetail` or some property of it (like `category` or whatever). Which property/key of `categoryDetail` is unique for each item? If there's such key/value pair, you can use reverse `while` loop instead of `forEach` to remove it. So, tell me which key/value is unique and i'll update the answer.

Comment: component.selectedCategoryDetails = [
        {
          category: "Drink More Water",
          habitDetails: [
            { trigger: "wake up", target: "drink a glass of water" },
          ],
          showDetails: false,
        },
        {
          category: "Drink More Water",
          habitDetails: [
            { trigger: "wake up", target: "drink a glass of water" },
          ],
          showDetails: true,
        },
      ];In spec file they have added like thisI think we have to pass the category detail please give the answer for the abovefor both html and ts

Comment: for your question category is unique for <ng-container *ngFor="let categoryDetail of selectedCategoryDetails"> as in html could you please update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're iterating in your html like:

`<... *ngFor="let categoryDetails of selectedCategoryDetails" ...>`

and your button with `deletedata()` is in the scope of ngFor, you can:

1. Change your iteration to include index of an item and trackBy function for updating the array in view:

`<... *ngFor="let categoryDetails of selectedCategoryDetails; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn" ...>`

2. On the button click pass the index to `deletedata()` method like:

`deletedata(index)`

3. Create your `deletedata` method like:

   ```
   deletedata(index:number){
       this.selectedCategoryDetails.splice(index, 1);
       // other code here, like calling api
       // to update the selectedCategoryDetails source
       // etc.
   }
   ```
4. Create `trackByFn` method like:

   ```
    trackByFn(index,item){
        return index;
    }
   ```

EDIT: Without index

If you want to iterate over `selectedCategoryDetails` in the ts file, without using ngFor with index in your html, you can have your `deletedata` like this:

```
deletedata(categoryDetails:any){
    for (let i = this.selectedCategoryDetails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (this.selectedCategoryDetails[i] === categoryDetails.category) {
        this.selectedCategoryDetails.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
}
```

It will iterate over `selectedCategoryDetails` backwards and remove the `categoryDetails` if it finds it in the array of objects.

Now, you only need to pass the `categoryDetails` to `deletedata` in your html:

`(click)="deletedata(categoryDetails);customHabitPopovers.hide()"`

Comment: Thanks @Misha Mashina, can we write iteration in ts file(using foreach) instead of html (ngFor)with the above requirement could you please help me on this I tried to add but not working as expected could you please edit the above one

Comment: Are you able to send the index to `deletedate` method?

Comment: I have edited my code please check that one and it would be helpful for me if you give the solution.thank you